# Making an iAd Pop Up Above a Toolbar

Tags: ios, iad

I have an app with a UINavigationController where I set the toolbar to visible. I want to display iAds, but they always pop up from the very bottom of the screen. I'm doing the sizing -- here's a log:

```
2012-10-08 09:52:17.722 Whos Here[21330:c07] INFO showBannerView:animated:
2012-10-08 09:52:17.723 Whos Here[21330:c07] INFO layoutAnimated with ADBannerView(#c14fed0, {{0, 436}, {320, 50}},  child of UIView(#c153930)
2012-10-08 09:52:17.724 Whos Here[21330:c07] INFO layoutAnimated content frame {{0, 0}, {320, 416}}
2012-10-08 09:52:17.724 Whos Here[21330:c07] INFO layoutAnimated banner frame {{0, 436}, {320, 50}}
2012-10-08 09:52:17.724 Whos Here[21330:c07] INFO layoutAnimated shrinking content frame {{0, 0}, {320, 366}}
2012-10-08 09:52:17.725 Whos Here[21330:c07] INFO layoutAnimated shrinking banner frame {{0, 366}, {320, 50}}
```

Am I trying to do something that is fundamentally incorrect or bad (i.e., against the HIG)?

Thanks,

Steve